# Need advice on submenus

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

So currently, I have to design some Menu bars with many options when clicked. But I have Menu bars part settled, what I'm lost about is I want to have 2 images. For instance if I click 'View', it'll drop down 'Original Image' & 'Scaled image' and if I clicked either one, it will show me respective images with the correct images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

scaled_img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 500))
cv2.imshow('Original image', img)
```

From my original code; and I'm not sure where to insert above codes(if correct), to below.

```
def showImg(self):
    load = Image.open('image.jpg')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)       
    img = Label(self, image=render)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=0,y=0)
```

Comment: You can use `Pillow` module to resize image, no need to use `OpenCV`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, assuming if I were to use Pillow instead, how do I proceed?

Comment: Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Pillow` module to resize image instead of `OpenCV`.  Below is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('500x600')

        # initialize the images
        img = Image.open('image.jpg')
        self.original_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        img = img.resize((400, 500))
        self.scaled_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)

        # create the menu bar
        menubar = Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        file.add_command(label='New')
        file.add_command(label='Open')
        file.add_command(label='Save')
        file.add_command(label='Save As')
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.client_exit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

        view = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        view.add_command(label='Original Image', command=lambda:self.showImg(self.original_img))
        view.add_command(label='Scaled Image', command=lambda:self.showImg(self.scaled_img))
        menubar.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

        # create a label to show the image
        self.imgbox = Label(self)
        self.imgbox.place(x=0, y=0)

    def showImg(self, img):
        self.imgbox.config(image=img)

    def client_exit(self):
        self.destroy()

Window().mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you provide more information on the errors?  It works in my Python 3.7.3 environment.

Comment: It means that you are using Python 2.  Change `super().__init__()` to `Tk.__init__(self)`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks that works! But then I have another issue when I try to make a new menu bar with this code: https://imgur.com/a/83pouyj (apologise as it'll be too messy if i post entire code here), the error is: AttributeError: client exit

Comment: You need to define `client_exit()` function in `Window` class, see my update answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Just a couple more question if you don't mind. How do I add title on my window? I was using this from my previous code but I'm not sure if it's correct; https://imgur.com/a/CfVA9Tp : Also, if I were to add more commands like rotating images, how would it be?

Comment: Use `title(...)` to set the title of the main window.  For image operations, refer to [Pillow Document](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Thank you but I keep getting title not defined although I have define it with                         def title(self) self.title()

Comment: For my posted code, add `self.title('My Program Title')` after `self.geometry(...)`.

Comment: Hey, I have another question if you don't mind answering. I have the code ready working but when I add another command for rotate with this code; https://imgur.com/a/lV7JVUN                     , when I run it the 'rotate' image appears in a new window and when I press Rotate Image, it doesn't appear

Comment: Don't call `.show()` as it will show the image using the default program registered.  And in your image of code, there is no `self.rotate_img` defined.  BTW, please accept my answer if it has solved your initial question.

Comment: I have accepted it, thank you. How do I define it? I'm totally novice at this

Comment: It is similar to `self.scaled_img`.

Comment: Change `img.rotate(45)` to `img = img.rotate(45, expand=1)`.

Comment: Hey, I would really appreciate if you could help me with something. I have Tello Edu Drone with me where when its on it'll capture images/videos etcc. I have this particular code here: https://imgur.com/a/Zb32I4d ; but it tells me "No Module named Tello". I have installed this Tello into my directory and such.

Comment: If you put the `tello.py`, `tello_control_ui.py` and `main.py` in same directory, you should not get the error.

Comment: Well, that works but now it says import libh264decoder ( i have moved this folder into the same directory as the rest), ImportError: DLL load failed: specified module not found

Comment: You need to build the required DLL.  I think it is not easy for you to build it because it requires some libraries.

Comment: Any other ways I could possibly achieve this?

Comment: If you have cloned `Tello-Python` project, there is a zip file `tello_video_dll(ForWin64).zip` in the root directory of the project.  Unzip it to the directory of `main.py`.

Comment: Did that, nothing change I'm afraid. :(

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again, following up your answer above (not the tello), apparently when I try to run the same thing you showed, I'm getting error such as "https://imgur.com/a/j6DldiS"... All awhile I was doing something else, barely even touch this code. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It seems like `_imagingtk.pyd` is missing in `Pillow` module directory.  Try to reinstall the module again.

Comment: okay so i did pip uninstall pillow (thinking that it succesfully uninstalled) so i tried to reinstall back but then it says requirement has been met. When i try to run my original program, I got "No Module named PIL". Edit: nvm apparently it wasn't uninstalled fully. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Also is there any other ways I could directly message you? It seems that I have more questions to ask and its getting full here

Comment: I'm not sure how to even create a chat room, do you mind making one?

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    # Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):
        img = Image.open("001.png")
        img = img.resize((250, 250))  ## The (250, 250) is (height, width)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        quitBtn2 = Label(root, image=photo)
        quitBtn2.image = photo
        quitBtn2.pack()
```

> **Image Module**
>
> The Image module provides a class with the same name which is used to
>   represent a PIL image. The module also provides a number of factory
>   functions, including functions to load images from files, and to
>   create new images.
>
> https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html